# child div goes outside parent div

Tags: css, html, css-float, overflow

Currently I am designing a website using CSS and HTML etc. But I have faced a problem there : my child div goes outside the parent div when I add floating to the child. The site resides here [my web design](http://7sisters.in/test/mintbite/)

Comment: A vague question. Which is your child div and parent div?

Answer (score 22):

Be more specific. Where is the problem on the website?

Try to add this to css, so parent will know about the size of the child element:

```
#parent{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to clear after your float.

Try adding this css:

**CSS**

```
.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Test the follwing CSS

```
.parentDiv {
    float: left,
    width: 200px,
    height: 30px
```

}

```
.childDiv{
    float: left,
    width: 100px,
}
```

The child division should be included in the parent one, you can use border on both element to make sure.