# Children div overlapping parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a **parent div** where **children div** are added. I use pagination set to five.
On large screen everything is fine but on smaller device (14.00-inch display that has a resolution of 1920x1080 pixels) the **children divs** are overlaying the **parent div** at the bottom.

[image]

The whole height of the **children div** can differ depending on how many **children div** are displayed (1,2,3,4 or 5)

This is the CSS of my **parent div**:

```
header.nav_masthead {
    padding-top: 6.5rem;
    background-color: #345a61;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image:;...;
}
```

The div where the `children div` are added:

```
<div id='fav_list'  class="w-75  mx-auto" style='background-color: transparent; height: auto;'>
```

This is my page HTML:

```
{% block content %}

<header class="masthead" >

  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <h2 class="intro-text text-center" style="color: beige;">Bienvenue sur ton compte {{ user }}</h2>
    <hr class="divider1 my-4" />

    <div class='w-75 mx-auto  row d-flex justify-content-around mb-3'>
      <h3 class="intro-text text-center account_items" style="color: beige;">Produit recherché</h3>
      <h3 class="intro-text text-center account_items" style="color: beige;">Produit de substitut</h3>
    </div>
    </div>

  <div id='fav_list'  class="w-75  mx-auto" style='background-color: transparent; height: auto;'>

    {% for saved in saved_list %}

    <div class='row d-flex justify-content-between'>

      <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 49%;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-2 my-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block" style="width:auto; height:auto; max-width:100px; max-height:100px; "
              src="{{ saved.original_product.picture }}">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'finder:detail' saved.original_product.id %}"
                  class="aaccount">{{ saved.original_product.real_name }}/ {{ saved.original_product.real_brand }}</a>
              </h5>
              <img src="/static/finder/img/nutriscore-{{ saved.original_product.nutrition_grade}}.svg"
                style="width:70px;"><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 49%;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-2 my-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block " style="width:auto; height:auto; max-width:100px; max-height:100px; "
              src="{{ saved.sub_product.picture }}">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'finder:detail' saved.sub_product.id %}"
                  class="aaccount">{{ saved.sub_product.real_name}}/ {{ saved.sub_product.real_brand }}</a>
              </h5>
              <img src="/static/finder/img/nutriscore-{{ saved.sub_product.nutrition_grade}}.svg"
                style="width:70px;"><br>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1 my-auto mx-auto">

          <button type ='button' class=' btn substitut' value='{{ saved.id }}'>{% csrf_token %}<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button>              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  </header>

    <div id='navigation'>                      
        {% if paginate %}
        <div  style="background-color: #E8A75D; overflow: auto; ">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        {% for i in page_range %}
        {% if i == 1%}       
        <span><button class='btn nav_button first ' value='{{ i }}'>{{i}}</button></span>
        {% else %}
        <span><button class='btn nav_button ' value='{{ i }}'>{{i}}</button></span>
        {% endif %}        
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}    
    </div>         


{% endblock %}
```

What should I do to make my div  `'fav_list'` not overlapping my div `'.nav_masthead'`?

Comment: Is there any other CSS files related?

Comment: Try doing [The Clearfix Hack](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp) and [Another article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [child div goes outside parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777013/child-div-goes-outside-parent-div)

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.